# Unable to add libpng library in my project

Tags: iphone, xcode, png, static-libraries, libpng

I am new to iPhone development and trying to load PNGs using libpng but unable to add it to my project after trying so much. I've got following errors while adding libpng to my project. Please help me how to get rid of these errors:

- "_deflateReset", reference from...
- "_inflateEnd", referenced from...
- "_*inflate", referenced from...
- "_deflate", referenced from...
- "*inflateInit*", referenced from...
- "_crc32", referenced from...
- "*deflateInit2*", referenced from...
- "_inflateReset", referenced from...
- "_deflateEnd", referenced from...

Comment: Show your import/include headers.

Comment: I haven't import any header in my code. I just added the libpng library as shown in the screenshot below and it is giving these errors.

Comment: This the screenshot of my project. Hope it helps u understand my problem:
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/5939/screenshot20100810at641.png

Comment: Underneath your #import EAGLView.h statement, try #import png.h

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those errors are link errors, not compile errors, right?  I think those are symbols from zlib, not libpng.

EDIT TO ADD: try adding libz.dylib to the project.